Help with the result of a Mann-Kendall test
I'm testing the tendency of precipitation, with a data point per day, for many years. As you can imagine, the dataset oscillates wildly between days and many points are 0. I used library(trend) and performed the test as mk.test(data$vals). I obtain
Mann-Kendall trend test

data:  data$vals
z = 19.312, n = 8334, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true S is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
           S         varS          tau 
4.788320e+06 6.147390e+10 1.488993e-01

Where varS is very high, I guess due to oscillatory behaviour of the data. But I'm surprised by the very low p-value, indicating that a trend exists, and at the same time tau not far from 0. There should be stationality (summer without precipitation) but I wasn't expecting a trend.
Are the previous values reasonable and the test valid?

Can you l[lease edit the post to include a plot?
